# remove ;# characters and number from xsl value (person /People group)- itemsyle.xsl

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt, item-styles

I'm retrieving like this

```
 <xsl:call-template name="RemoveHtml">
           <xsl:with-param name="String" select="@Person.title"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
```

Result looks like this
Neill@uxxx.com33Field@uxxx.com

How can i remove the number "33" and replace with space or comma.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0: 2.0 makes this kind of thing much easier with the replace() function, which uses regular expressions.

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, then try:

```
normalize-space(translate(xxx, '0123456789', '          '))
```

which replaces all digits with spaces and then collapses multiple spaces to a single space.

Comment: Thanks Michael. it did the trick but i had to stick with 1.0 :(